# Two definitions show up on "peek" view and command click

Tags: flowtype, visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for past 6 months now and have faced an unusual situation when I started using `flow` within VSCode.

Before I used `flow`, the *peek* definition and goto definition features were working perfectly alright. But, since I have integrated `flow` in my project - I am facing this issue:

[image: 2 definitions found]

I am not sure why I see two definitions under `../@types/package/..`. Is there someway I can clear this by removing the definitions or clearing the cache ?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was something very weird. A workspace setting in VSCode caused this:

> "flow.useNPMPackagedFlow": true,

As soon as I toggled it to `false`, everything starting to function normally. I had set it to `true` to enable `flow`.

I am not sure if this is one hundred percent resolved, but it is good enough for now.